# 1) gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Tags: clang, gtk, msys2, gtk4

I am facing an issue in gtk 4 with MSYS2 and c language in VS-code, it shows an error of : gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    //gtk code comes here

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone can solve this problem.[Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqWlQ.png)

I tried to reinstall the software (GTK 4 with MSYS2) but it is not working althought.

Comment: What MSYS2 package did you install for GTK? What MSYS2 environment are you running (as indicated by the magenta text in the terminal prompt)? Did you add any extra compiler flags?

Comment: What command line are using to compile your code?